# How to find out if the "NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.default.set" result was successful

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore

I am writing data from my application to iCloud as follows. How to determine whether this process was successful?

```
NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.default.set("data", forKey: "key")  
NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.default.synchronize()
```

*Reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore*

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the value after setting it to see if it was set correctly.

I think it is important to note that your data is actually a string so you would use the string() function of NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.default to get the value. The function required to get the stored value will change depending on the value's variable type.

```
// Set value
let data: String = "data"
NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.default.set(data, forKey: "key")  
NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.default.synchronize()

// Try to get value
if let dataString = NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.default.string(forKey: "key") {
    if dataString == data {
        // The data stored correctly
    } else {
        // Handle condition if data is not stored
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but this solution is not working. Because even if it blocks the application, it returns the data instantly at runtime. However, when you make the data writing section comment line and open the application again, the data will not return.